# Dynamic boost threads running methods of objects stored in a vectors with shared pointers

Tags: c++, multithreading, boost

I have a camera class which is an abstraction of a network camera. The class has a method rxImageThread() which is an image server, essentially. I want to run n servers in n threads for n cameras where n is dynamically set (from a config file).

The camera objects are stored in a vector:

```
std::vector<boost::shared_ptr<camera> > cameras;
```

I create the camera objects in a loop:

```
cameras.push_back( boost::shared_ptr<camera> (new camera(ip, controlPort, dataPort, imagePort, name)) );
```

I have a vector to store the threads:

```
std::vector<boost::shared_ptr<boost::thread> > threads;
```

In a loop, I want to enable the rxImageThread()'s of each camera to run in a thread:

```
for(int i = 0;i<cameras.size();i++){
   threads.push_back( boost::shared_ptr<boost::thread> (new boost::thread(&camera::rxImageThread, &cameras[i]) );
   cameras[i]->startRx();
}
```

However, I get an error along the lines of:

```
‘void (camera::)()’ incompatible with object type ‘boost::shared_ptr<camera>’
```

Which suggests that I should use code similar to:

```
threads.push_back( boost::shared_ptr<boost::thread> (new boost::thread(std::mem_fn(&camera::rxImageThread),&cameras[i]  ));
```

However, this gets the same errors.

I'm a little lost as to what's going on here, let alone how to fix it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

a `shared_ptr<>` is not an address. you have to call `.get()` on it to get the object address.

such as:

```
threads.push_back( boost::shared_ptr<boost::thread> (new boost::thread(&camera::rxImageThread, cameras[i].get()) );
```

Looking further than solving this problem, I am wondering whether it might be cleaner to have a controller class that owns the camera and controls the thread lifetime. This way you can guarantee that the camera is not deleted before the owning thread terminates.

EDIT:

here's a complete program that demonstrates the idea. Thread safe starting and stopping of cameras. no memory leaks or possibility of threads outliving cameras:

```
#include <boost/thread.hpp>
#include <boost/shared_ptr.hpp>

#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;


namespace {
    boost::mutex _cout_mutex;
}
// a cut-down camera class

struct camera
{
    camera(std::string hostname, unsigned short port)
    : _hostname(hostname)
    , _port(port)
    {}

    std::string description() const {
        std::ostringstream ss;
        ss << _hostname << ':' << _port;
        return ss.str();
    }

    std::string _hostname;
    unsigned short _port;
};



struct camera_controller
{
    camera_controller(const std::string& hostname, unsigned short port)
    : _camera(hostname, port)
    , _stop(false)
    {}

    void start() {
        boost::unique_lock<boost::mutex> outlock(_cout_mutex);
        cout << "starting " << _camera.description() << endl;
        outlock.unlock();

        assert(!_thread_ptr);
        _stop = false;
        _thread_ptr.reset(new boost::thread(boost::bind(&camera_controller::camera_thread, this)));
    }

    void stop() {
        if (_thread_ptr) {
            boost::unique_lock<boost::mutex> outlock(_cout_mutex);
            cout << "stopping " << _camera.description() << endl;
            outlock.unlock();

            notify_stop();
            _thread_ptr->join();
            _thread_ptr.reset();
        }
    }

    ~camera_controller()
    {
        stop();
    }

private:

    void camera_thread()
    {
        while (!time_to_stop())
        {
            // do things with the camera
            boost::unique_lock<boost::mutex> outlock(_cout_mutex);
            cout << "working: " << _camera.description() << endl;
            outlock.unlock();
            boost::this_thread::sleep_for(boost::chrono::milliseconds(1000));

        }
        boost::unique_lock<boost::mutex> outlock(_cout_mutex);
        cout << "shutting down: " << _camera.description() << endl;
        outlock.unlock();
    }

    void notify_stop() {
        boost::unique_lock<boost::mutex> outlock(_cout_mutex);
        cout << "notify stop for " << _camera.description() << endl;
        outlock.unlock();
        _stop = true;
        // would normally signal a condition variable here
    }

    bool time_to_stop() const {
        // test the stop condition
        return _stop;
    }

private:
    camera _camera;
    boost::shared_ptr<boost::thread> _thread_ptr;

    // this could be a condition variable in a real application
    bool _stop;
};


struct application
{
    typedef boost::shared_ptr<camera_controller> control_ptr;

    control_ptr add_camera(const std::string& host, unsigned short port)
    {
        control_ptr p(new camera_controller(host, port));
        p->start();

        // tightest lock possible on shared resources
        boost::unique_lock<boost::mutex> lock(_cameras_mutex);
        _camera_controllers.push_back(p);
        return p;
    }

    // for example...
    void destroy_camera_by_index(size_t i)
    {
        boost::unique_lock<boost::mutex> lock(_cameras_mutex);
        control_ptr cam_ptr = _camera_controllers[i];
        _camera_controllers.erase(_camera_controllers.begin() + i);
        lock.unlock();

        // note - this blocks until the camera thread is stopped
        cam_ptr->stop();
    }

    size_t camera_count() const {
        boost::unique_lock<boost::mutex> lock(_cameras_mutex);
        return _camera_controllers.size();
    }


private:

    std::vector<control_ptr> _camera_controllers;
    mutable boost::mutex _cameras_mutex;
};

int main()
{
    application app;
    app.add_camera("camera_a", 0);
    app.add_camera("camera_b", 1);
    app.add_camera("camera_c", 2);
    app.add_camera("camera_d", 3);
    app.add_camera("camera_e", 4);

    while(app.camera_count() > 2) {
        boost::this_thread::sleep_for(boost::chrono::seconds(2));
        size_t i = rand() % app.camera_count();
        app.destroy_camera_by_index(i);
    }

    boost::this_thread::sleep_for(boost::chrono::seconds(2));

}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, I didn't know about the get() method. I think the last argument for boost::thread should now be cameras[i].get() rather than &cameras[i].get() though?

Comment: correct. my apologies. Think carefully about the controller idea. I think it'll save you a lot of headaches when you start adding and removing cameras dynamically.

Comment: So the controller would be a class with the camera objects and threads and would pass the camera objects into threads? Rather than have the threads within the camera objects? At the moment, the main thread owns a class which creates the cameras from a config file and then initiates the threads and sets start and stop variables from the main thread (a state machine). Why is this way harder? Thanks again, by the way!

Comment: I would suggest that one controller owns one thread and one camera (encapsulation). Then you just need to keep a vector of camera_controllers. Now you have one single point of ownership and the camera_controller can protect your program by joining the thread in the destructor, to ensure that the thread does not outlive the camera. Safety by design.

Comment: I'll post an example in a few mins if you like

Comment: I think I understand but that would be really useful, thank you!